# Fail assertion opencv mat.inl.hpp line 930

Tags: opencv, mat

I have a trivial problem but I don't know how to solve it. I just wanna do a simple "foreach" of a Mat to view rgb values. I have next code:

```
for(int i=0; i<mat.rows; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<mat.cols; j++)
    {
        int value_rgb = mat.at<uchar>(i,j);
        cout << "(" << i << "," << j << ") : " << value_rgb <<endl;
    }
}
```

The mat is 200 rows x 200 cols. When I print on console the results, just in the final the programs fails with next error:

```
**OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 <(unsigned)size.p[0] && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211) >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 1 5) == elemSize1()) in unknown function, file c:\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.hpp, line 537**
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: how `mat` is declared?

Comment: excuse me to everyone, the problem is not here where i posted the issue. Its on other function, so excuse me and thanks for the helpness abobe all to you, Arjun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below piece of code will help you in accessing the rgb pixel values.You have to access three channels to view RGB values.

```
for(int i = 0; i < i<mat.rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < mat.cols; j++)
        {
            int b = mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[0];
            int g = mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[1];
            int r = mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j)[2];
            cout << r << " " << g << " " << b << value_rgb <<endl ;
        }
    }
```

To read pixel value from a grayscale image

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <highgui\highgui.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
    int main()
{
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("5.jpg",0);

for(int j=0;j<img.rows;j++) 
{
  for (int i=0;i<img.cols;i++)
  {
    int a;
    a=img.at<uchar>(j,i);
     cout<<a<<endl; 
  }
}

cv::imshow("After",img);
waitKey(0);
}
```

**Updated**
This code reads all the grayscale values from an image and results in frequent occurring vales (Number of times the value as occurred). i.e

Number of times pixel value '0' as appeared,

Number of times pixel value '1' as appeared, ... & so on till 256.

```
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <highgui\highgui.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
    int main()
{
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("5.jpg",0);

//for(int j=0;j<img.rows;j++) 
//{
//  for (int i=0;i<img.cols;i++)
//  {
//    int a;
//  a=img.at<uchar>(j,i);
//     cout<<a<<endl; 
//  }
//}
vector<int> values_rgb;
for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<20; j++)
    {
        int value_rgb = img.at<uchar>(i,j);
        values_rgb.push_back(value_rgb);
        //cout << "(" << i << "," << j << ") : " << value_rgb <<endl;
    }
}
// Sorting of values in ascending order 
vector<int> counter_rg_values;
for(int l=0; l<256; l++)

{
    for(int k=0; k<values_rgb.size(); k++)
    {
        if(values_rgb.at(k) == l)
        {
            counter_rg_values.push_back(l);
        }
    }
}
//for(int m=0;m<counter_rg_values.size();m++)
//cout<<m<<" "<< counter_rg_values[m] <<endl;
int m=0;
for(int n=0;n<256;n++)
{
    int c=0;
    for(int q=0;q<counter_rg_values.size();q++)
    {
        if(n==counter_rg_values[q])
        {
            //int c;
        c++;
        m++;
        }
    }

    cout<<n<<"= "<< c<<endl;
}
cout<<"Total number of elements "<< m<<endl;

cv::imshow("After",img);
waitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: But, if the image is converted just before to grayscale?

Comment: int Gray = mat.at<uchar>(i,j);  use this line  to read grayscale value.

Comment: It continues failing in the last (i,j). Exactly when it checks the value on (199,199)

Comment: What I wanna know is the counter of a rgb value is repiting.

Comment: @JaimeMenendezLlana Check it out i have updated it for grayscale image. I didn't get you about the ptroblem regarding RGB??

Comment: It would be better about grayscale but i dont mind if the solution is in RGB. I just know how it works the function "calcHist()" from OpenCV. For that, Im developping my own function to know the working

Comment: @JaimeMenendezLlana Did it work for you.!! the grayscale code!! Is it what you wanted???

Comment: No! Im explainnig you my goal of that. What i want is understanding why is ocurring this issue. What I say on the last comment is the context from my problem for you can have a reference about my program. I don't want nobody do by me my own job. I know the use of this amazing comunity webpage.

Comment: @JaimeMenendezLlana Sorry,i seriously didn't get your problem.!! What problem u are facing?? Whats the issue??

Comment: The issue is the erros which appears in my first comment. I think it could be excesive size of my mat (200x200), because I'm saving on the first vector 400000 rgb_values... It would have sense to resize the mat smaller dim?

Comment: Thanks a lot Arjun!!! I need this final loop. Now I understand perfectly how it works this algorythm!!

Comment: @JaimeMenendezLlana Happy that it really worked for you.!! Please accept this as an answer if it has helped you.